# Kibana discovery not showing all types within an index

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, kibana-5

I have an elastic search index which contains five different types of documents.

Totally I have 50,000 documents, each mapping type contains 10,000 documents.

```
index name : fruits
mapping types : apple, orange, banana, papaya, grapes.
```

Now I indexed elastic search with kibana.

When I hit `*` in discover tab it shows only 10,000 documents of type `grapes`.
Other documents were not shown.

But when I use `developer console` in Kibana, match all query shows 50,000 documents.

> How can I index all documents into Kibana? or How can I change mapping
>   types to view other documents of different types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Initially I checked the box 'Index contains time-based events' during
  indexing of documents.
- But some of mapping types were not time-based events.

so those documents were not displayed

Answer (score 1):

By default Kibana displays first 500 rows in `discover` page. If you would like to see more rows then you need to modify following setting to desired number(in your case `50000`) from `Advanced Settings`:

> **discover:sampleSize** (Default: 500)  The number of rows to show in the
>   table

You can read more about kibana advanced settings [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/5.3/advanced-options.html#advanced-options).

Comment: But it displays the document count as it is..But in my case the document count is 10,000

Comment: Yes, `document count` is different and it's a just simple aggregation. As you have `10,000` for `discover:sampleSize` you are able to see only 10k rows. If you want to see 50k then increase it to that number. `Warning: A very high number may lead to crash your kibana`

Comment: But for other index I get document count more than 20,00,000 . But my problem is not the size.

Comment: Please let us know what exactly you are looking for? If you want to see some specific set of docs in discover page then you can use and leverage elasticsearch queries.!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found the solution. Initially U checked the box 'Index contains time-based events' during indexing of documents. But some of mapping types were not time-based events. so those documents were not displayed.

Comment: Glad! you found the solution. Write your findings as answer, it could help others in future!